# Homestead : how to specify the MariaDB version to use?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I would like to use [Laravel homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/homestead) pre-packaged Vagrant box with **MariaDB version 10.6**.

After [reading the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/homestead) and check all release, I cannot found how to specify a specify version to use, or which [homestead realease](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases) I shoud use.

```
features:
    - mariadb: true
    - mysql: false

services:
    - enabled:
        - "mariadb"
```

Comment: You can ssh into the homestead environment after running it and then check if you have the version of the db you are looking for and point to it. Or else there are config for the db which you can modify as well.

Comment: @Adi, yes, I can check the version, always 11.X but I need to use the specific version 10.6. Do you know where is the config fil you are talking about ?

Comment: Sorry i meant installation files, they are usually hidden files inside the repo itself and you check if the necessary version was installed. If so then just ssh into the environment and point your app to the desired version. Else you would have to install it using ssh